# Pause Flexslider when YouTube video plays

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I've read and tried a ton of ways to get Flexslider working with YouTube (so that the Flexslider slideshow pauses when a video is playing) and am still stumped. The first video in my flexslider plays correctly, pausing the slideshow, but the second video keeps playing without pausing the slideshow, and when I try re-playing the first video again same thing - no slideshow pause.

Here's a live example that uses the code below, which also shows the HTML for the iFrame and such: http://tmi.friendlyweb.us/people/sample-page/

And here's my jQuery: https://gist.github.com/FriendlyWP/8375571

Ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!